# Possibility of custom scroll with AngularJS using webix datatable?

Tags: angularjs, datatables, webix

I am using webix datatable in AngularJS, I want to use [custom scroll](http://docs.webix.com/samples/60_pro/03_api/01_customscroll.html) feature of webix datatable in my AngularJS application.

So can anyone guide me for the same?

Comment: @Mistalis I want to use in webix datatable, and they provide custom scroll option in its JS library, I want to use that default features in my project, [refer this](http://docs.webix.com/desktop__scroll_control.html#webixcustomscroll) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Custom scroll feature of webix is tightly linked to Webix components and can't be used with any other widgets.